# Using sqoop incremental import to a hive table is not supported?

Tags: hadoop, import, hive, sqoop

Have been trying to do incremental import to a hive table using sqoop .. but unfortunately showing as Append mode for hive imports is not yet supported. Please remove the parameter --append-mode

Answer (score 0):

You can't do append operations on to hive using Sqoop. However you can import data onto any HDFS location and create a hive external table on top of that.

Below link has detailed information:

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/11373/sqoop-incremental-import-in-hive-i-get-error-messa.html

Comment: Thank you and currently implementing the same way.